# Is it possible to have vim key bindings in terminal?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, vim, zsh

I'm getting used to vim bindings (like pressing w to go to word, dw to delete a word, and such) and it's modes (insert, normal, visual), and, out of curiosity would like to know: is there some kind of implementation of this behaviour of modes and bindings from vim to my terminal?

Have insert mode, normal mode and such...

Answer (score 73, accepted):

It has *insert* and *normal* modes (the insert mode is default, and escape for normal mode).

When in *vi normal mode*, you can launch the full $EDITOR to edit the current line with `v` (the same can be achieved when bash is in *emacs mode* with `C-x C-e`).

In bash: `set -o vi` You can run it at the command line for just this session or add it to your .bashrc file.

Many programs use `readline` for input, and you can make any of them use vi-style keybindings by setting up your `.inputrc` with

```
set editing-mode vi
set keymap vi
```

In zsh, if you change your `EDITOR` environment variable, the shell will match it.

Comment: Pretty neat. Do you know if it's possible to have some kind of .vimrc as well, but for this uses? For example, adding different mappings to <ESC>...

Comment: @Somebody: Not `.vimrc` since you're still using the shell's built-in editor, but you can configure key bindings in [`.inputrc`](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rluserman.html#SEC9) for all readline applications (such as bash), in `.bashrc` for bash specifically, in `.zshrc` for zsh.

Comment: Checkout the [bind builtin](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/bind1.html)

Comment: Note that on OS X, you'll need to put the `put -o vi` in ~/.bash_profile instead of ~/.bashrc .

Comment: I notice that the cursor appearance doesn't change in the different modes bash w/ vi key bindings.  Is there any way to make it do that?  It would be nice to have a visual indication of what mode I'm in.

Comment: ^ Why `put` (and not `set`), does Mac have it's own version of `bash`?

Comment: For a visual indicator you can put `set show-mode-in-prompt on`, `set vi-ins-mode-string "+"` and `set-cmd-mode-string ":"` in your `.inputrc` file.

Comment: @Will That worked, with a few changes. Namely, I added:
```set show-mode-in-prompt on```
```set vi-ins-mode-string "+"```
```set vi-cmd-mode-string ":"```

Comment: How to paste a clipboard in terminal in this case? Neither the `<C-v>, <C-S-v>` nor vim registers work.

Comment: `you can launch the full $EDITOR to edit the current line with v ` this doesn't seem to work with zsh. it is entering visual mode. any idea? i am using [powerlevel10k](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k) theme, but i don't think that could be the reason right?

Comment: On WSL, you'll need to restart the terminal to see the changes advised by @Soap take into affect.