# Capture colors with tmux buffer copy (hardcopy)

Tags: tmux, colors, ansi-term

I am using the following line in `tmux` for getting a "hardcopy" feature like in GNU Screen:

```
bind H capture-pane \; save-buffer -b 0 ~/tmux.hardcopy \; delete-buffer -b 0
```

However, the ANSI colors are not captured to the file. How do I make `tmux` save the ANSI escape sequences so that the hardcopy will be colored too?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*tmux* 1.8 added the `-e` option to `capture-pane`; using this new option causes the captured data to include the effective escape sequences.

```
bind H capture-pane -e \; save-buffer ~/tmux.hardcopy \; delete-buffer
```

(You can omit `-b 0` since buffer 0 is the default buffer if one is not specified.)