# Capture colors with GNU screen hardcopy

Tags: gnu-screen, colors, escape-characters

Using GNU Screen (Screen version 4.06.02 (GNU) 23-Oct-17), I want to use hardcopy to save the colors of a specific screen.

When I run `screen -x nameofmyscreen -X hardcopy /tmp/hardcopy`, the resulting file is only the text of the screen. (Similar result to when I press Ctrl+A, h).

Can GNU Screen save the colors of the screen into a file?

(Similar to [Capture colors with tmux buffer copy (hardcopy)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103108/capture-colors-with-tmux-buffer-copy-hardcopy#) )

Comment: What you *can* do is turn logging on before running the command you want to capture the output of. See `log on`, and `logfile`.

Comment: Do you want a text version with escape codes (something you could `cat` to see again) or an image?

Comment: Yes, I want escape codes, so this could be `cat`ed back.