# Save all terminal output to a file, after the fact

Tags: command-line, clipboard, output, terminal-emulator

This:
[Save all the terminal output to a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/200637/save-all-the-terminal-output-to-a-file)

Except after the fact. Meaning that instead of preparing to record or pipe all output to a file, I am dealing with output that has already taken place, and that I omitted to record to a file. Rather than to spend minutes scrolling up 7000 lines of output, copying and pasting that to a document, I have to think there is an easier way to get the current output.

Considering that this may depend upon the terminal emulator, I am using Konsole and zsh in this case.

How can I save the terminal output to a file after the fact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `konsole`, `File->Save output as` works as does `CTRL-SHIFT-S`, but you will only save what is in the buffer.

Comment: +1.   `tmux` can also do this, in any terminal emulator.  see [Write all tmux scrollback to a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26548/write-all-tmux-scrollback-to-a-file).   note, though, that if you're running tmux on a remote host (e.g. via ssh) then the buffer will be saved on the remote host, not on the local machine you're running your terminal emulator on.

Answer (score 0):

I use `script` for this matter. It's easy, simple, and out of the box.

- First invoke `script` in your terminal:

```
# script output.txt
Script started, file is output.txt
```

- Start running your commands normally.
- Once you decided to get your commands and all the outputs, run `exit`:

```
# exit
exit
Script done, file is output.txt
```

- All your outputs will be in output.txt.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to question at:
[Save all the terminal output to a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/200637/save-all-the-terminal-output-to-a-file/765384#765384)

For xfce4-terminal use the accels.scm file.

For instance, to reassign Ctrl-Shift-s from 'set title' to 'save contents' Open to edit: ~/.config/xfce4/terminal/accels.scm

Then search for 'save-contents' and modify the line as follows:

```
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/terminal-window/save-contents" "<Primary><Shift>s")

; This will map 'save the entire scrollback buffer to a file' to the Left_Ctrl-Shift-s keystrokes.

; NOTE: commented lines start with a ;
```

Within an xfce4-terminal select 'Terminal, Save contents..' or simply Left_Ctrl-Shift-s.

A filemanager will will open to allow you to select where to save the file containing the screen buffer output.