# `jj` vim keybinding for zsh terminal

Tags: terminal, zsh, vim

I have recently set vim key binding to my zsh terminal on OSX, as described in [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4870/is-it-possible-to-have-vim-key-bindings-in-terminal).

However, the deault keybindings doesn't have the mapping from `jj` to `insert mode -> normal mode` transition.

Howe can I implement this keybinding for my zsh terminal?

Comment: Hi, this is explained far better in the [zsh manual](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html). This manual will also help you setup keybinds for both command mode (normal mode) and insert mode as well as general keybinds.

Comment: @SeetheMoar I didn't even know zsh had a manual. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bindkey -M viins jj vi-cmd-mode
```

will bind `jj` to the `vi-cmd-mode` widget in the `viins` (`vi` insert mode) keymap.

Now, you need to type those two `j`s within `$KEYTIMEOUT` centiseconds (40 by default) of each other. Otherwise, that inserts two `j`s. That also means that when you enter `j` in insert mode, it won't be displayed until you press another key or you wait for those 0.4 seconds.

Check [the manual](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html) for details.